# how to use a template inside a kendo mvvm grid column command?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm, kendo-template

I have an MVVM Grid binded to the 'LabsViewVM' ViewModel, shown below. 
Column commands 'activate', 'suspend', 'abolish' are binded through the 'click' event to the LabsViewVM's transitLab method/handler, which executes just fine.

```
<div    id="labs_view"
        data-role="grid"
        data-bind="source: labs, visible: isVisible, events: {edit: createLab, dataBound: dataBound, dataBinding: dataBinding}"
        data-detail-init="LabsViewVM.detailInit"
        data-detail-template= 'lab_details_template'
        data-selectable="row"
        data-scrollable= "true"
        data-resizable= "true"
        data-sortable= "{'allowUnsort': false}"
        data-pageable="{ 'pageSizes': [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 50], 
                         'messages':  { 'display': '{0}-{1} από {2} Διατάξεις Η/Υ', 
                                        'empty': 'Δεν βρέθηκαν Διατάξεις Η/Υ',
                                        'itemsPerPage': 'Διατάξεις Η/Υ ανά σελίδα', 
                                        'first': 'μετάβαση στην πρώτη σελίδα',
                                        'previous': 'μετάβαση στην προηγούμενη σελίδα',
                                        'next': 'μετάβαση στην επόμενη σελίδα',
                                        'last': 'μετάβαση στην τελευταία σελίδα' }}"
        data-editable="{ 'mode' : 'popup', 'template': $('#lab_create_template').html()}"
        data-toolbar="[{ 'template' : $('#lab_toolbar_template_labs_view').html()  }]"
        data-columns="[{ 'field': 'lab_id', 'title':'Κωδικός Διάταξης Η/Υ', 'width':'65px', 'hidden' : true},
                       { 'field': 'lab_name', 'title':'Ονομασία', 'width':'440px'},
                       { 'field': 'lab_type', 'title':'Τύπος', 'width':'150px', 'hidden' : true},
                       { 'field': 'lab_state', 'title':'Λειτουργική Κατάσταση', 'width':'150px'},
                       { 'field': 'rating', 'title':'Αξιολόγηση', 'template' : $('#labs_view_rating_column_template').html(), 'width':'85px'},
                       { 'field': 'positioning', 'title':'Τοποθεσία', 'width':'180px', 'hidden' : true},
                       { 'field': 'lab_special_name', 'title':'Ειδική Ονομασία', 'width':'180px', 'hidden' : true},
                       { 'field': 'creation_date', 'title':'Ημερομηνία Δημιουργίας', 'width':'150px', 'hidden' : true},
                       { 'field': 'last_updated', 'title':'Τελευταία Ενημέρωση', 'width':'150px'},
                       { 'field': 'created_by', 'title':'Δημιουργία από', 'width':'130px', 'hidden' : true},
                       { 'command': [{'text':'Ενεργοποίηση', 'click':LabsViewVM.transitLab, 'name':'activate'},
                                     {'text':'Αναστολή', 'click':LabsViewVM.transitLab, 'name':'suspend', },
                                     {'text':'Κατάργηση', 'click':LabsViewVM.transitLab, 'name':'abolish'}], 
                                    'title': 'Ενέργειες', 'width':'500px', 'hidden': LabsViewVM.hideLabTransitColumn() }
                      ]">
</div>



var LabsViewVM = kendo.observable({

    transitLab: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var parent_grid = $(e.delegateTarget).data("kendoGrid");

        var transition_dialog = $("#transition_dialog").kendoWindow({
                    modal: true,
                    visible: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    width: 500,
                    pinned:true,
                    open: function(){lots of code...}
        }).data("kendoWindow");

        var transitTemplate = kendo.template($("#lab_transit_template").html());
        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        transition_dialog.content(transitTemplate(dataItem));
        transition_dialog.center().open();
    }   

});
```

I'm quoting from https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/kendo-mvvm-framework, some information for the click property just to stress the way kendo differentiates its click event from the traditional one.

"The click property binds the click event of a button to a function inside of the View-Model. It is a shortcut to the events binding that we will see later. Unlike a traditional click event wire-up, **the Kendo UI framework will pass context data to the event handler to allow for a richer event-handling experience. For example, when a click event is bound within a row template, the event argument passed to the event handler will have access to the item from the source collection.** This allows the event handler to operate against that Model data directly without any further DOM exploration and keeps all of the observable functionality in place."

Having that in mind, I was able to access the parent grid, inside transitLab, through the event parameter 'e'.

I then had to change my implementation and use a kendo template for the column commands, because I needed to add some logic to the appearance of the command buttons.

So i replaced

```
{ 'command': [{'text':'Ενεργοποίηση', 'click':LabsViewVM.transitLab, 'name':'activate'},
                                         {'text':'Αναστολή', 'click':LabsViewVM.transitLab, 'name':'suspend', },
                                         {'text':'Κατάργηση', 'click':LabsViewVM.transitLab, 'name':'abolish'}], 
                                        'title': 'Ενέργειες', 'width':'500px', 'hidden': LabsViewVM.hideLabTransitColumn() }
```

with

```
{ 'command': [{'name':'commands', 'template': $('#labs_grid_command_column_template').html()}], 'title': 'Ενέργειες', 'width':'270px' }
```

and template :

```
<script id="labs_grid_command_column_template" type="text/x-kendo-template">   
    #if( some condition ){#
        <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-activate" href="\#" data-bind="click: transitLab"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Ενεργοποίηση </a>
        <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-suspend" href="\#" data-bind="click: transitLab"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Αναστολή </a>
        <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-abolish" href="\#" data-bind="click: transitLab"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Κατάργηση </a>
    #}#
</script>
```

but it doesn't work.

My code crashes inside transitLab handler, because its event 
parameter 'e' **does not get populated with the same context data as before**.
For example e.delegateTarget in the first case points to the grid, whereas in the second case points to the command button itself.

I don't get it. Shouldn't these two implementations have the same effect?? Please help!